# Node js package.json script not getting argument

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have a nodejs server and I'm writing some migrations.
For some reason my script is not recognizing the desired name for the migration:
this is my script:

```
"create-migrate": "migrate-mongo create $NAME"
```

This is supposed to let me use something like :

```
npm run create-migrate init-data
```

and create a migration named "init-data".

What happens - it's just creating the migration using the "$NAME" as the name...
I'm not sure if it has something to do with me working on windows or not,
anyway I will be thankful for some light here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need the `$NAME` argument

just use like this

`"create-migrate": "migrate-mongo create"`

and what ever you pass after `create-migrate` will become it name

example

`npm run create-migrate init-data`

Comment: lol thats it :)
I took this example script from a friend and didnt know whats up.
Thanks dud!